# Matching list of words in any order but only if adjacent/separated by a maximum of n words

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have only been able to find advice on how to match a number of substrings in any order, or separated by a maximum of n words (not both at once).

I need to implement a condition in python where a number of terms appear in any order but separated by e.g. a maximum of one word, or adjacent. I've found a way to implement the "in any order" part using lookarounds, but it doesn't account for the adjacent/separated by a maximum of one word issue. To illustrate:

```
re.search("^.*(?=.*word1\s*\w*\sword2)(?=.*\w*)(?=.*word3\w*).*$", "word1 filler word2 and word3")
```

This should match `"word1 word2"` or `"word1 max1word word2"` and `"word3*"`, in any order, separated by one word as in this case - which it does. However, it also matches a string where the terms are separated by two or more words, which it should not. I tried doing it like this:

```
re.search("^.*(?=\s?word1\s*\w*\sword2)(?=\s?\w*)(?=\s?word3\w*).*$", "word1 word2 word3")
```

hoping that using `\s?` at the beginning of each bracketed term instead of `.*` would fix it but that doesn't work at all (no match even when there should be one).

Does anyone know of a solution?

In the actual patterns I'm looking for it's more than just two separate strings, so writing out each possible combination is not feasible.

Comment: Not all string problems are regex problems. This isn't a good fit for regular expressions. Some combination of `input.split()` and `word in list_of_words` is probably better.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your answer - how would I implement these specific requirements (adjacent/separated by a max of n words) with that though?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is not perfectly clear but you could try this, assuming *word1*, *word2* and *word3* are known words

```
(?:word1(\s\w+)?\sword2)|(?:word2(\s\w+)?\sword1)|word3
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ik9PGO/2/)

Comment: Building a regex with all permutations quickly becomes infeasible.

Comment: I agree, that's why I assume this is only this simple case to handle. The question is not clear enough imo

Comment: Hi Stephane, apologies for not being clearer - there are some cases where it's just two terms so yes that would be an option, but I also have other cases where it's a much larger number of terms and where it would become quite a pain to write out all the potential combinations!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to identify patents related to AI using a keyword search in abstracts and titles

In that case, I wouldn't recommend regular expressions at all.

Instead,

- **Use a library that provides [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).**

  This is how your code knows that that "program", "programming", "programmer", etc. are related, and is much more robust than a regular expression solution and is more likely to be semantically accurate.
- **Use a library that can generate n-grams.**

  [N-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) are essentially tuples of subsequent words from a text. You can infer that words appearing in the same tuple are more likely to be related to each other.
- **Use a library of stop words.**

  These are words that are so common as to be unlikely to provide value, like "and".

Putting this all together, 3-grams for

> inductive randomword logic and programming

would be something like

- (induct, randomword, logic)
- (randomword, logic, program)

Applying this to an arbitrary article, you can then look for stemmed n-grams with whatever terms you wish. Adjust `n` if you find you're having too many false negatives or positives.

This isn't the place for a complete tutorial, but a library like [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) provides [all](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#module-nltk.stem) [of](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#module-nltk.collocations) these features.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much, that's very helpful! Is there a way to make the function work with longer terms or regular expressions instead of just single words? To explain a bit more what the purpose is, I'm trying to identify patents related to AI using a keyword search in abstracts and titles. So for example, I would want to implement a search that will match the following: ((inductive 1w logic) 1D programm+) where "1w" stands for separated by a maximum of 1 word, 1d stands for in any order and separated by a maximum of 1 word, and + is equivalent to \w* in regex terms.

Comment: This should match "inductive logic programm" but also "programm inductive logic" or "inductive randomword logic and programming", etc. And then there are cases that are similar in principle, but where it's more than two terms in any order. I've tried applying the function above as follows: my_function("this is about inductive logic and programming", "inductive\s*\w*\slogic", "programm\w*") which evaluates to "False", presumably because I haven't told python that the strings are regular expressions.

Comment: "I'm trying to identify patents related to AI using a keyword search in abstracts and titles"—this would have been good information to include in your question. You're going down an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627) path by prescribing the solution you want instead of asking about the question itself. An n-gram search using stemming will probably give much better results. I'll try to provide a new answer later today.

Comment: @Pia, I have rewritten my answer. This isn't the place for a complete tutorial, but I hope this gives you enough of an answer to move forward.

Comment: Hi Chris, many thanks for your answer and apologies for the delayed reply. After some discussion with my co-authors we concluded that we wanted a deterministic rule rather so ended up just generating all the potential constellations. But it's definitely useful to know about this method for future use!